# Getting error "readFtpReply: Socket operation timeout.' while downloading with chilkat library on android device

Tags: android, ftp, chilkat

Our app is using the chilkat library for downloading files from FTP/SFTP and when it comes to huge file like 1 GB, we see the below error but for smaller file it works. The FTP server is Windows based.
For the same file, if we use AndFTP apk, it does download the file completely.

We want to confirm if there is any setting that needs to be changed on the FTP server or is there any config to be done on the client side to resolve the issue.

````
06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):   GetFile:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     DllDate: May  7 2019

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.78

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     UnlockPrefix: VMWRKM.CB4062020

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     Language: Android Java

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     VerboseLogging: 0

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     originalGreeting: 220 Microsoft FTP Service

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     remotePath: PFILES/ASRampServiceOreo_1/FPU_ATLAS_02-13-15.00-ON-U08-STD.zip

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     localPath: /sdcard/FPU_ATLAS_02-13-15.00-ON-U08-STD.zip

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     ProgressMonitoring:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):       enabled: yes

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):       heartbeatMs: 0

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):       sendBufferSize: 65536

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     --ProgressMonitoring

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     autoGetSizeForProgress:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):       getSize64ByName:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         sizeCmd:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):           sizeCmdInner:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):             simpleCommand:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               sendCommand:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):                 sendingCommand: SIZE PFILES/ASRampServiceOreo_1/FPU_ATLAS_02-13-15.00-ON-U08-STD.zip

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               --sendCommand

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               readCommandResponse:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):                 replyLineQP: 213 1059949952

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               --readCommandResponse

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):             --simpleCommand

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):           --sizeCmdInner

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         --sizeCmd

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):       --getSize64ByName

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     --autoGetSizeForProgress

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     downloadToFile:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):       localFilePath: /sdcard/FPU_ATLAS_02-13-15.00-ON-U08-STD.zip

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):       Replacing existing local file

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):       downloadToOutput2:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         modeZ: 0

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         binaryMode: 1

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         setupDataConnection:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):           passive transfer mode

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):           setupPassiveDataSocket:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):             sendCommand:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               sendingCommand: PASV

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):             --sendCommand

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):             readCommandResponse:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               replyLineQP: 227 Entering Passive Mode (52,191,166,243,234,205).

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):             --readCommandResponse

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):             dataConnect:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               hostname: 52.191.166.243

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               port: 60109

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               socketOptions:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):                 SO_SNDBUF: 524288

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):                 SO_RCVBUF: 4194304

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):                 TCP_NODELAY: 1

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):                 SO_KEEPALIVE: 0

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               --socketOptions

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):               dataConnectSuccess: 1

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):             --dataConnect

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):           --setupPassiveDataSocket

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         --setupDataConnection

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         sendCommand:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):           sendingCommand: RETR PFILES/ASRampServiceOreo_1/FPU_ATLAS_02-13-15.00-ON-U08-STD.zip

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         --sendCommand

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         readCommandResponse:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):           replyLineQP: 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         --readCommandResponse

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         downloadRate: 2406259

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         totalNumBytesReceived: 1059949952

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         receiveTimeMs: Elapsed time: 440497 millisec

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         readCommandResponse:

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):           Failed to read FTP control channel reply.

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):           readFtpReply: Socket operation timeout.

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         --readCommandResponse

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):         No final status reply.

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):       --downloadToOutput2

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):       downloadToOutput: Elapsed time: 500989 millisec

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     --downloadToFile

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):     Failed.

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):   --GetFile

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391): --ChilkatLog

06-29 08:44:30.363 E/A(10391):

06-29 08:44:30.364 I/A_FtpDownloadHandler(10391): Download failed: FPU_ chilkat TLAS_02-13-15.00-ON-U08-STD.zip```
````

Comment: `totalNumBytesReceived: 1059949952` How big was that file?

Comment: Its a complete android OS bsp, so its around 1GB as mentioned in the descriprion.

Comment: I asked for the exact size in bytes of course. Compare both also.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if updating to the latest version of Chilkat resolves the problem.  The latest version is v9.5.0.83.